# How to automatically assign a value to a field?

Tags: ms-access

I have:

- `Table_A` with this fields: `ID` (primary key, unique), `Name`, `Attribute_A`
- `Table_B` with this fields: `ID` (number), `Name`, `Attribute_B`

I would like that `Table_B.Name` filled in this way:

```
UPDATE Table_B
SET Table_B.Name = Table_A.Name
WHERE Table_B.ID = Table_A.ID
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` in an `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE Table_B
INNER JOIN Table_A ON Table_B.ID = Table_A.ID
SET Table_B.Name = Table_A.Name
```

Note that both tables are required to be updateable, not only the one being updated.

Comment: thanks. it soulds good. but where should I put this code in Access?

Comment: Eh... It's a query. Just run it as a query.